# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in c, reverse polish calculator

Tags: c

Code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXOP 100
#define NUMBER '0'

// functions as external thing

int getop(char[]);
void push(double);
double pop(void);

int main()
{
    // defining variables n stuff
    int type;
    double op2; // operand 2
    char s[MAXOP];

    while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case NUMBER:
            push(atof(s));
            break;
        case '+':
            push(pop() + pop());
            break;
        case '*':
            push(pop() * pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
            break;
        case '/':
            op2 = pop();
            if (op2 != 0.0)
                push(pop() / op2);
            else
                printf("error: Zero divisor\n");
            break;

        case '\n':
            printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
            break;

        default:
            printf("error:unknown command %s \n", s);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Terminal Output-

```
cc     reversepolish.c   -o reversepolish
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_getop", referenced from:
      _main in reversepolish-fc0241.o
  "_pop", referenced from:
      _main in reversepolish-fc0241.o
  "_push", referenced from:
      _main in reversepolish-fc0241.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [reversepolish] Error 1
```

I am trying to build a reverse polish calculator from the book of Dennis Ritchie "The C Programming Language".

Comment: You actually have to [implement those](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Ancillary:Polish_calculator) somewhere before you can link.

Comment: There is more code than that —  you've copied the code from p76, but the rest of the code is on p77-79.

Comment: Enjoy the debugging exercise. Pay attention to the program output.

Comment: Indeed, you have declared the gettop, pop and push functions, but they also need to be defined (i.e., they need a body of code). At the moment you only tell the compiler these functions exist, but it does not yet have the code, you either need to implement it yourself or link with a library that implements those functions.